# How do I get this function to account for empty cells?

Tags: vba, excel

I feel like the logic is correct ...I have a big list of words in the A column, if it happens that one of those words in that A column are a substring of the words in my other column then I want to replace it, otherwise leave the word alone.

The following script crashes for empty cells and I get numerous `!Value` errors.

```
Function Find_Bad_Replace_Good(inputValue as String) as String
  Dim v As Long, vList As Variant
    With ActiveSheet
        vList = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value2
        For v = LBound(vList, 1) To UBound(vList, 1)
            If CBool(InStr(1, inputValue, vList(v, 1), vbTextCompare)) Then
                Find_Bad_Replace_Good = vList(v, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next v
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I'm getting no errors running your code. Can you provide a data sample  of the first column as well as a method argument that gives an error?

Comment: Yes for example if abc is in the column a try abcd in another column and run the function. it enters the second loop and causes a !Value error on my excel

Comment: Call the function with what parameters? You need to be more specific. If it's a custom formula you need to say so and provide an example of how you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this is the issue...but....I guess the below condition will be true when the data in A column (vList(v,1)) is empty....you may want to skip it, if empty

```
If CBool(InStr(1, inputValue, vList(v, 1), vbTextCompare)) Then
```

Change it to

```
If vList(v, 1) <> "" And CBool(InStr(1, inputValue, vList(v, 1), vbTextCompare)) Then
```

Comment: I thought similarly but my vList definitely isnt empty :(

Comment: Please provide a more detailed answer and properly format your code.